# MailEnable error connection timed out

Tags: centos7, plesk

I am getting these errors from MailEnable, the OS is CentOS. The errors are from /var/log/maillog as suggested by @OlegNeumyvakin.

```
 Sep  8 03:33:12 localhost journal: plesk sendmail[38416]: handlers_stderr:$
 Sep  8 03:33:12 localhost journal: plesk sendmail[38416]: SKIP during call$
 Sep  8 03:33:12 localhost postfix/pickup[35664]: 66B7B21F2D4F: uid=0 from=$
 Sep  8 03:33:12 localhost postfix/cleanup[38422]: 66B7B21F2D4F: message-id$
 Sep  8 03:33:12 localhost postfix/qmgr[9634]: 66B7B21F2D4F: from=<root@loc$
```

The email cannot send nor receive anything. I am trying to get it to work since it is for a site and it needs to send/receive emails.

Comment: Is there something interesting in /var/log/maillog ?

Comment: a lot of connection timed out

Comment: Hm, not looks like related issues. Ok, could you please rewrite your question with step-by-step and more details about what your are trying to do and what you get. Why there is CentOS and MailEnable error message.

Comment: I will update tomorrow everything. CentOS is the OS the server is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your virtual address by command:

```
 postmap -q mail@example.tld  hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
```

`virtual.db` is Berkeley DB file

you can check it content with Berkeley DB dump util:

```
# db5.1_dump -p /var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual.db

VERSION=3
format=print
type=hash
h_nelem=4103
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
 drweb@example.tld\00
 drweb@localhost.localdomain\00
 kluser@example.tld\00
 kluser@localhost.localdomain\00
 mail1@example.tld\00
 mail1@example.tld\00
 postmaster@example.tld\00
 postmaster@localhost.localdomain\00
 root@dexample.tld\00
 root@localhost.localdomain\00
 anonymous@example.tld\00
 anonymous@localhost.localdomain\00
 mailer-daemon@example.tld\00
 mailer-daemon@localhost.localdomain\00
DATA=END
```

you can install this util with `yum install libdb-utils`

Also in case you have issues with sending mail you can check limitations on outgoing email messages at `Tools & settings > Mail Server Settings` and if you have enabled them `Tools & settings > Outgoing Mail Control`

Comment: The email is in the .db and the outgoing mail control is disabled, so it shouldn't limit it.